# More iterations with less time?

Tags: java, loops, iteration

I just had nothing to do and started messing around with `for` loops in Java, so I wrote the following function

```
static int getCurrentTime() {
    return (int)System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

which simply gets the time for me.

Now I have my main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int s = 0;
    int beginTime = getCurrentTime();
    for (int j = 0; j < 2000000000; ++j)
        for (int i = 0; i < ####; ++i)
            s++;

    System.out.println("done in " + (getCurrentTime() - beginTime)+
                       " milliseconds!");
}
```

Now when I put 1 in the place of ####, I get the following output

```
done in 4118 milliseconds!
```

But when I put 3 in the place of ####, I get the following output

```
done in 11 milliseconds!
```

How is this possible? How did more iterations take less time? I'm really confused about what's happening here.

Comment: Since you do not use `s` variable JIT may have decided to completely remove your both for-loops. JIT is very smart and can simply eliminate such code. Microbenchmarking in Java is **really** non-trivial: https://www.baeldung.com/java-microbenchmark-harness

Comment: @Ivan I've just tested that theory and, even after using `s`, I'm still seeing this.

Comment: You are measuring the time it takes for the JVM to detect the code doesn't do anything and do a code replacement for that. How long this takes can vary significantly between runs and based on a number of factors which don't matter for most real programs.

Comment: Using JMH it shows 10E-10 seconds per method (Warmup Iteration   2: ˜ 10?¹° s/op) which basically confirms that JIT eliminated that loop completely